# IFrame src video change issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iframe, video

Im attempting to load a youtube video into an iframe and also when a button is clicked it would change the src of the video and then change the video in the iframe. I have tried this a few ways and the src changes but the initial video stays the exact same.

here is all my javascript and jquery

```
   <script>            
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Seller/VideoLoad?videocategory='+'@Model.VideoCategory',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var video2 = document.getElementById('Video2');
            video2.src = data;
            alert(video2.src);
}
    });
    $(function() {
        $('.text').click(function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            alert($(this).attr("name"));
            alert("TEST");
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("name"));
        alert($(this).attr("src"));

        });
    });
        });
```

and here is the iframe and where the button is loaded that changes the iframe video

```
 <iframe style="float: left" width="500" height="315" id="Video2">

        </iframe>


 @foreach(var video in Model.VideoList) {
          var url = @video.Value;
<input type="button" class="text" name="@video.Value" value="@video.Text"  />
<br />
      }
```

why wont the video change when the src changes? and is there a way to make it change?
thanks already

Comment: For one thing, you don't need the `$(function() { ... })` wrapper if you're already putting this inside `$(document).ready(function(){...})`...

Comment: well that is true but that doesnt help the problem ha.

Comment: Secondly, why are you trying to set your .text button's /src/ to the name? Don't you want to set the /iframe/'s src?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean to change the iframe's src?

```
    $('.text').click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).attr("name"));
        alert("TEST");
        $('#Video2').attr("src", $(this).attr("name"));
    alert($('#Video2').attr("src"));

    });
```